# Why am I seeing InvalidProxyConfigurationWarning when using an HTTPS proxy with urllib3?

Tags: python, https, proxy, python-requests, urllib3

When using a `urllib3.ProxyManager()` with an HTTPS proxy URL I'm seeing a warning called `InvalidProxyConfigurationWarning` on version 1.25.9 of `urllib3`. I didn't get this warning before, what does it mean?

Answer (score 2):

This warning is new in `urllib3` v1.25.9 and means that your proxy which is configured to use HTTPS is not doing what you intended.

See this issue for more information: https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/1850
Copied below is the text from the issue.

urllib3 up to v1.25.x doesn't support HTTPS proxies. When connecting to an HTTPS URL, urllib3 contacts the proxy via HTTP instead of HTTPS **even if your proxy URL specifies HTTPS**. In urllib3 v1.26.x we're planning on supporting HTTPS proxies properly and are giving an early warning to users to switch their proxy URLs from HTTPS to HTTP to not encounter issues when upgrading later.

```py
import urllib3

# HTTPS proxy, should change!
http = urllib3.ProxyManager("https://1.2.3.4")
http.request("GET", "https://example.com")  # Warning would be raised here.

# Switch to this, will maintain current behavior when connecting to HTTPS URLs.
http = urllib3.ProxyManager("http://1.2.3.4")
http.request("GET", "https://example.com")  # Warning won't be raised, same behavior as above.
```

Your proxy may be configured externally like in a `HTTPS_PROXY` environment variable or via `requests.Session(proxy_url=...)` or configured by your OS.

(FYI I'm the current lead maintainer of urllib3)